# Find columns in a data frame most similar to one column

Tags: r

I have data from a VCF file that shows the genotype of variable sites in the genome for a set of individuals. Rows are each individual and columns are the site in the genome (bp). Genotype is encoded by a 0, 1 or 2 (homozygote, heterozygote, homozygote):

```
individual 80738047 81161037 81161055 81285600 81354721 81355142
indiv_1       0       1         1        2        0      0
indiv_2       1       1         2        0        0      1
indiv_3       2       2         1        2        2      0
etc
```

Each of these individuals has a specific chromosomal haplotype, also encoded by a 0, 1 or 2, which I have in a different file such that:

```
individual Haplotype
indiv_1       0 
indiv_2       0 
indiv_3       2
etc
```

There are about 5500 sites with a nucleotide variant in the region I'm looking at, and I need to find sites that are highly correlated with the haplotype of the individuals. Ideally, I'd like to have an output where the most correlated columns to the individual haplotype are given in an ordered object.

While I can `left_join()` the data frames by individual and then conduct lm[] and output an R^2 value for individual column pairs, I don't know how to conduct an R^2 between the genotype column and all the other columns in the matrix in one command.

Additionally, I'm not sure how to output the resultant values into an orderable object. Any ideas?

**IMPORTANT TO NOTE:** There is some missing data throughout the data frame.

Comment: To ask about an edge case, what happens if two or more columns be tied as being the most "similar?"  How do you break the tie?

Comment: Ideally, the output would be a list of columns ranked by similarity rather than a single "most similar" column. I am trying to generate a list of candidate SNPs that may be diagnostic of this specific haplotype, for further testing.

Comment: Maybe extend your MCVE to also have some missing data?